# Is it appropriate for a cruise ship beer dispenser to charge gratuity/tip?

Tags: usa, cruising, tipping, caribbean

We are currently on a Caribbean cruise operated out of Miami. On board there is a beer dispenser (PYOB - Pour Your Own Beer), which charges per ounce directly to my room. The machine is self-operated, although a staff member does have to refill the keg periodically.

There is no mention of a tip or gratuity, nor is there an option to amend or remove one, but the amount that is charged to my room is always 18% more than what is displayed on the machine.

In American Cruise ship culture, is this an appropriate practice?

Comment: I'd separate American and cruise ship culture here. Pour-your-own-beer bars are rare in America, and while I haven't taken a grand tour of them, I don't believe there's any tipping typically involved unless you're getting food. Cruise ships have particular automatic gratuity policies that are nothing like most US restaurants and bars.

Comment: Related (but no duplicate): https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/111863/is-there-a-way-to-cancel-automatic-tipping-on-carnival-cruise-before-the-last

Comment: Hey, beer dispensers need money too! You think they get paid enough to put their kids through college?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In American/Cruise ship culture, is this an appropriate practice?

**YES.**  It is appropriate for a US based cruise/cruise line.

The gratuity is automatically added to *all* beverage purchases.  Automatic gratuities are pooled so all Beverage Service crew will share it.

The machines still require regular **cleaning, servicing and maintenance** which is done by the bar staff.

You will find the **same scenario on Royal Caribbean with their Bionic Bar** where the Gratuity is also automatically added.

You will find the **same scenario on Norwegian with their wine dispensers** where the Gratuity is also automatically added.

Comment: A better framing of the question is probably whether it is appropriate for the machine to display a price that is 18% below what it actually charges. (And then the answer might well be that it is in line with US practice -- IIUC they're not usually displaying the actual price-to-the-customer on goods in shops either).

Comment: Yes, it is 100% inline with US customs to not display a gratuity amount on menus.  This is the case ashore as well.  Neither Carnival or Royal Caribbean do so on board.  Norwegian does for whatever reason they have chosen.

Comment: Yes, it is also 100% in line with US customs to not display the total amount due on an item because tax rates very by jurisdiction.

Comment: Given that you've noted the fact that the machine is operated by bar staff, is it fair to take from this that those bar staff would otherwise not receive a living wage?

Comment: @quant They receive *more* than a living wage.  Jobs on cruise ships are highly sought after.  Tipping/gratuity is part of the de facto compensation plan in American culture.  No one is being taken advantage of.  In fact (I may make a video about this) the crew on my last transatlantic sailing was eager to begin the Caribbean season because...wait for it...Americans tip much better so they make a lot more money.

Comment: It’s not a *gratuity* if you can’t opt out. Or can you?

Comment: @JonathanReez It might be itemized as a Service Charge, in which case no.  This is still in line with North American customs.

Comment: @Johns-305 100% inline with customs, sure, but can you really say it is appropriate to display a price that is under what you actually charge the customer?

Comment: @Johns-305 example: if you buy bread, you don't pay the price, plus extra for the flour, extra for the oven usage, extra for the rent of the shop, extra for the electricity bill. No. All of that is included in the price, which is somewhere between the cost of the production, and the value for the consumer.

Comment: @njzk2 Seriously?  Tipping a baker is not a thing.  Tipping a bartender is.  Bartenders take care of the self-serve dispense just as they would a tap behind the bar.

Comment: @njzk2 Prices in North America are displayed before tax and gratuity.  So again, yes.

Comment: @Johns-305 can you find any good justification as to why, though? what's the difference?

Comment: @njzk2 Justification for what? North America culture?  I'm not a fan of Tipping, bit it's how service staff here is compensated.  Bar staff tends to the machine which requires just as much upkeep and cleaning as any other tap.

Comment: @Johns-305 for what -> for systematic mandatory tipping. "it's part of the culture" is a poor argument, as a reminder it's a relatively recent phenomenon

Comment: @Johns-305 don't get me started on "before tax price". why should anyone a/ care about the price before tax b/ have to calculate the real price themselves? It makes no sense.

Answer (score 10):

The beer dispenser gratuity is one of those "automatic gratuities" charged by the cruise lines.  It is important to note that automatic gratuities, whether from the beer dispenser or various line items on a bill are not given to staff as tips.  Instead, this money is collected by the cruise line, which in-turn applies the funds towards as much as 95% of their staff's salary as documented in [this article](https://www.findlaw.com/legalblogs/law-and-life/is-automatic-gratuity-on-cruise-ships-legal/). This contradicts the historical definition of gratuity.

The oxford dictionary (via google) defines gratuity as:

> a tip given to a waiter, taxicab driver, etc.

The cambridge dictionary [defines](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/gratuity) gratuity as:

> a small amount of money for someone who has provided you with a
> service, in addition to the official amount and for their personal
> use

The general consensus is that a gratuity is optionally provided by an individual that received services, as an extra reward for good service, in addition to whatever base compensation an entity earns; *and that entity gets to keep it*. The fee collected from the beer dispenser has some ethical problems in this area:

1. The beer dispenser automatically takes gratuity regardless of exceptional service.
2. The extra fee is collected by the cruise line.
3. The gratuity's real purpose is to pay employee salaries (so that the cruise line doesn't have to).
4. If the claim is that the fee is towards maintenance, electricity, etc., then there are other kinds of fees this charge could fall under- convenience or maintenance for example.  In some countries, the United States for example, organizations that charge additional fees for credit card transactions are supposed to display such extra fees at the point of sale and on your receipt. No one calls these fees "gratuity".  They are "surcharges".

The question of "is it appropriate?" is tricky- because it's a point of view. You can make various arguments for appropriateness- for example:

- is it ethical
- is it common practice
- is there any law against it
- does the practice unjustly hurt the livelihood of another

But given that the definition of "gratuity" is clear- it is supposed to be a tip, and management keeps the tips- I can say with confidence that the beer dispenser gratuity is *not* appropriate.

Comment: "The gratuity's real purpose is to pay employee salaries (so that the cruise line doesn't have to)":  the cruise line is still paying their salaries.  The real purpose of the gratuity is to allow the cruise line to advertise lower prices than it actually charges.